# Make interface implementations comparable with ==

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have a class `Product : IProduct`. All the code that uses products works with interfaces, interface implementation is supplied by an in-house DI container. What do I need to add to the interface and the class, so I can write code like:

`IProduct defectiveSku;`

`IProduct customerSku;`

....

`if(customerSku == devectiveSku)`

{

`// refund, blame someone else`

}

else

{

`// scare the customer away`

}

Comment: overload the comparison operator in the implementation its better to overload Equals though.

Comment: Why is it better? `==` operator leads to shorter, easier to read code.

Comment: In cases like this where the two objects are primarily for storing some data value they are semantically equivalent, but more importantly Equals is what is used by classes like Set, List, etc. to compare to existing values.  For instance, List.Contains(Foo) will call Foo.Equals(...) for each item in the List.  So if you want to have a List<IProduct> and call Contains with some SKU, you need to implement Equals.

Comment: Documentation on the above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx

Comment: Tnx Chris, that's a very good point. It would be good to have `==` working, but Equals is higher priority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `IEquatable<T>` interface:

```
interface IProduct : IEquatable<IProduct> { ... }
```

But you'll have to compare with the `Equals` method:

```
if (customerSku.Equals(defectiveSku)) ...
```

Comparing with `Equals` is better for an entity like `IProduct` because it better conveys the semantics of *entity equality* than the `==` operator; which normally conveys just *reference equality* or *value equality*.

Comment: Plus the DI container needs to be capable of injecting the implementation of IEquatable<T>...  Which could be interesting- what defines equality in a dynamically generated class?

Comment: @Chris Shain: What defines equality is the specific _implementation_ of the interface.

Comment: Also, the DI container just needs to inject the `IProduct` implementation.

Comment: True- my assumption (based on the wording of the question) was that the OP was not in a position to change the implementation provided.

Comment: Ahh, if that's not the case, he needs a _separate_ implementation of `IEqualityComparer<IProduct>`.

Comment: I currently have control of IProduct, Product and the code that uses them. If our home-built DI container won't work, I can switch to another.

`(customerSku.Equals(defectiveSku))` is IMHO harder to read than `customerScu == defectiveSku` and it works for a BCL reference type like `string`

Comment: Although strings are reference types, they have _value_ semantics.

Comment: You don't need to switch the DI container, since the comparison is expressed in the interface `IProduct`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, I suspect you actually want to overload Object.Equals(Object) or IEquatable.Equals(T), but since you have a DI container implementing the classes you might have trouble doing that, since the DI container (or the provided implementation) would need to know how to implement comparison.  If by chance you are using Castle Windsor, you can do it using a custom interceptor, similar to the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged here: http://www.hightech.ir/SeeSharp/Best-Implementation-Of-INotifyPropertyChange-Ever